# Is the SSID for wireless routers part of the link layer in the internet protocol suite?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, protocol, ssid

Ethernet, DSL and other cable connections for computers using them are links in the [Internet Protocl Suite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Suite), but I do not see the link layers referring explicitly to wireless communication. What are the protocols for wireless routers and are they part of the [Link Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Layer)? Does the identifier for SSID fall under the link layer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757419%28WS.10%29.aspx):

> a Service Set Identifier (SSID), also known as the wireless network
>   name, identifies the wireless network. The SSID is a name configured
>   on the wireless AP (for infrastructure mode) or an initial wireless
>   client (for ad hoc mode) that identifies the wireless network. **The
>   SSID is periodically advertised by the wireless AP or the initial
>   wireless client using a special 802.11 MAC management frame known as a
>   beacon frame**

Looks like the SSID falls under Layer 2 (of the OSI model) which is the Data Link Layer.

**EDIT**: Layer 2 of the OSI falls under the Link Layer for the IP suite.

So the answer to your question is: Yes, the SSID for wireless routers are part of the link layer in the internet protocol suite.